# About redirecting page to another with querystring in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I am creating online quiz. Here in 1st form i have dropdownlist for list of tests & start button. In the click of start button i am creating random list of questions(random ids). After clicking start button 2nd form appears here questions & their answers and next button displays. After clicking next button next random question i.e (2nd id from list which is created in first form) will appear. I want to identify each question with their id in addressbar when i am clicking next question.That means my first form : Main.aspx redirects to 2nd form(startexam.aspx?id=1) when i click to next button in this form then it should identify that question id.
Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Comment: Can you rephrase its very confusing , you already have the list why do you want to pass it via the querystring ?

Comment: Passing question or answer id in the query string is not a good idea, because a user may tamper with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you will have something like this: http://www.example.com/form.aspx?qid=1 ?
If yes, you can get the value for the querystring parameter qid by Request.QueryString["qid"];

Hope that helps. If I misunderstand what you said, please post your code.

Comment: i did like that when i am redirecting 2nd form it gives that id of question but after clicking next button in 2nd form next question will appear then that question id should change in querystring but its not changing

Comment: Do you update the value for the question id querystring parameter on the next button in the second form? It does not update by itself.

Comment: how i can update in next_ click event i have array of ids & i am fetching these values in next_click event only

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag instead of a button to navigate from one page to another.

```
<a href="http://www.onlinequix.com/q.aspx?id=10">Next</a>
```

If you really want to use a button, then I will suggest to use the `Session` (in server side) / `Cookies` (in client side) to store the question number according to your need.

Comment: I have session values for question id

Comment: ooops, I think you have changed your question while I was typing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asp.net Wizard control rather than make a page for every question.

Have a look here at these articles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Wizard_Control.aspx